# Currying doesn't work if returned function declared elsewhere

Tags: javascript, closures, currying

The following code works perfectly well:

```
// Returns a function that inherits parent's scope
const curry = argOne => argTwo => console.log(argOne, argTwo);

const initiateFunction = curry(1);
initiateFunction(2) // Outputs: "1 2"
```

My intention is to declare a returned function elsewhere in the code to make it re-usable.

Nevertheless, if I write:

```
const myLogger = argTwo => console.log(argOne, argTwo);

// Returns reference to a function that doesn't inherit parent's scope
const curry = argOne => myLogger;

const initiateFunction = curry(1); // Seems to be ok

initiateFunction(2); // ReferenceError: argOne is not defined
```

What's the problem & how to fix it?

Comment: `argOne` isn't inside the scope of `myLogger`. And `curry` doesn't use the argument passed to it; the reference to `argOne` is lost.

Comment: @ChrisG How do I fix it? If `curry`'d use argOne, would it help in any way?

Comment: You can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/drk5bpjq/

Comment: `myLogger` can't be aware of what `argOne` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confused due to the fact that currying at that point was a very new concept to me. Combined together with arrow functions it looks fantastic but is also harder to grasp.

If we re-write the example using the classic function definitions, it'll be very easy to understand why the second way doesn't work.

```js
const curry = argOne => argTwo => console.log(argOne, argTwo);
curry(1)(2) // -> 1 2

// Is equivalent to
function curry (argOne) {
  return function(argTwo) {
    console.log(argOne, argTwo)
  }
}
```

while in the second example, `myLogger` can't access to `argOne` as correctly stated in comments:

```js
const myLogger = argTwo => console.log(argOne, argTwo);
const curry = argOne => myLogger;

curry(1)(2) // -> Error

// Is equivalent to
function myLogger(argTwo) {
  console.log(argOne, argTwo)
}

function curry(argOne) {
  return myLogger // which has no idea what is argOne since declared outside of curry scope
}
```